# Эта серия игр должна быть также крута как раньше

Tags: слитно-раздельно, также

Эта серия игр "А" должна быть **также** крута как раньше. - Хотелось бы узнать , должно ли писаться "также" или "так же" в данном случае? Однозначно ли это?
Не изменится ли написание в случае, если предложение будет с уточнением -  Эта серия игр "А" должна быть **также** крута, как раньше была крута серия игр "Б"

Answer (score 2):

***Так же*** - раздельно в обоих случаях. ТАК (как?) - это наречие. ЖЕ - частица.

Как проверить? Частицу ***же*** легко можно убрать: ***Эта серия игр "А" должна быть так [же] крута, как раньше. - Эта серия игр "А" должна быть так [же] крута, как раньше была крута серия игр "Б"***